# How to make randomized numbers but if they are too close, change it

Tags: libgdx

I want to make randomized numbers but if they are too close, I want to make it a reroll or make it a number further away from the the other number or try to make it a little more spread out.

I guess I am not sure what exactly I want :/

Thanks in advance

EDIT: So the reason i am making randomized numbers is for spawning positions for units on sides of the screen so i want units to not be too close to each other essentially to make it look better.

Comment: Both of the anwers you've gotten will work for particular problems.  What problem are you trying to solve?  Why are you making the randomized numbers?

Comment: edited the topic with the purpose

Answer (score 1):

> I want to make randomized numbers but if they are too close, I want to
>   make it a reroll or make it a number further away from the the other
>   number or try to make it a little more spread out.

A random number generator sometimes produces numbers that are near each other.

If you don't want them so close together, maybe what you need is fixed numbers each with a small random perturbation.

Let's say you choose numbers 10, 20, 30, 40, and 50.  Then, you run a random number generator that gives you a number between -3 and +3.  You add this random number to each one in turn.  This produces numbers that aren't uniform, but they're not too close to one another.

Comment: this is an interesting alternative. Might end up using this but ill see what else could work.

Answer (score 0):

If a re-roll would be sufficient, you could just save the previous value, and then on the next iteration, if the difference between the two numbers is too small, call Math.rand() again. Maybe your sample space is too small?

Comment: i think this would get a little complicated with more than 2 numbers since it would have to compare with every single previous values?

Comment: If you're trying to compare against every previous value then you'll eventually run out of space for a random number given a range. What are you really trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

1. Get random position
2. If it's not good (too close to some other or what ever) go to step 1.
3. There you go! You got valid position. :)
   ...

Or...pre-calculate all valid positions, place them in some array and use rnd function to get array indexes - what array elements will use. That should be the faster solution (if you have huge number of units)...